# Apple IOS application and Delphi TidCmdTcpServer

Tags: iphone, ipad, delphi, tcpclient, tcpserver

I have a server process written in Delphi which has been in production for several years.  It is using the `TidCmdTcpServer` to communicate with the client (also written in Delphi and using the TidTcpClient).  This server uses has SSL encryption enabled.

I am contemplating writing an iPhone/iPad app to use in addition to the existing client.
I have searched but have been unable to find any examples of how to connect an IOS client to the SSL encrypted TidCmdTcpServer service running on windows.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Ken

Answer (score 0):

We've just started on an IOS app and I'd recommend looking at the creating a SOAP server using the components in XE2 (Indy components), especially if your responses are going to be quite complex, we also wanted to use an industry-standard approach to cross-platform communication.

The WSDL file can be imported into X-Code (though it needs to be converted into a different format first), SSL encryption works as expected, we pass back data formatted as XML which is easier for X-Code to process/interpret and we've seen faultless reliability and good performance.